# Transforming a List of 2-Tuples in Haskell

Tags: haskell

(Background: Trying to learn Haskell, very new to functional programming. Typically used to Python.)

Suppose I have a list of 2-tuples, a histogram:

```
let h = [(1,2),(3,5),(4,6),(5,3),(6,7),(7,4),(8,6),(9,1)]
```

In imperative terms, I want to change the second term of each pair to be the sum of all the previous second pairs. In Python, the following (admittedly complex) list comprehension could do it:

```
[(p[0], sum( [p[1] for p in histogram[:i+1]] ))
    for i, p in enumerate(histogram)]
```

assuming `histogram` refers to a list of 2-tuples like `h` above.

Here's what I have so far in Haskell:

```
zip [fst p | p <- h] (scanl1 (+) [snd k | k <- h])
```

This works, but I wonder:

- Is this reading through the list once, or twice?
- Can it be expressed better? (I expect so.)

In case it isn't clear, this is the expected output for the above:

```
[(1,2),(3,7),(4,13),(5,16),(6,23),(7,27),(8,33),(9,34)]
```

Comment: Your Haskell is pretty similar to what I'd write initially, and I think it is pretty clear; certainly easier to approach than the lens or bifunctor approach.  However, yes, it does walk the list multiple times.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use this function

```
accumulate = scanl1 step
        where step (_,acc) (p1,p2) = (p1,acc+p2)
```

Here is the result on your sample data:

```
*Main> accumulate h
[(1,2),(3,7),(4,13),(5,16),(6,23),(7,27),(8,33),(9,34)]
```

Comment: That is correct - if you don't discard the first values you don't need to put them back again. It is simpler to just write `accumulate = scanl1 step` though.

Comment: @duplode Did not know that function. Answer updated, thank you.

Comment: Excellent! Very readable, too. Don't know why I'm trying to make everything in Haskell harder than it really is. :)

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist I guess it is a necessary phase :-D

Answer (score 5):

If you're new to Haskell this might be a little too early, but [lens](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) offers a nice succinct way:

```
> scanl1Of (traverse . _2) (+) h
[(1,2),(3,7),(4,13),(5,16),(6,23),(7,27),(8,33),(9,34)]
```

You can easily accumulate only the first one by switching to `_1`:

```
> scanl1Of (traverse . _1) (+) h
[(1,2),(4,5),(8,6),(13,3),(19,7),(26,4),(34,6),(43,1)]
```

Or accumulate all values as a sort of nested list:

```
> scanl1Of (traverse . both) (+) h
[(1,3),(6,11),(15,21),(26,29),(35,42),(49,53),(61,67),(76,77)]
```

Answer (score 4):

Well,... `(,)` is a `Data.Bifunctor` and `Data.Biapplicative`

```
scanl1 (biliftA2 (flip const) (+))
```

is what you want.

---

A `Functor` is such a type `f` that for any `a` can apply any function `a->b` to `f a` to get `f b`. For example, `(a,)` is a `Functor`: there is a way to apply any function `b->c` to translate `(a,b)` to `(a,c)`.

```
fmap f (x,y) = (x,f y)
```

A `Bifunctor` is such a type `f` that for any `a` and `b` can apply two functions `a->c` and `b->d` to `f a b` to get `f c d`. For example, `(,)` is a `Bifunctor`: there is a way to apply any pair of functions `a->c` and `b->d` to translate `(a,b)` into `(c,d)`.

```
bimap f g (x,y) = (f x, g y)
```

A `Biapplicative` is such a type `f` that for any `a` and `b` can apply `f (a->c) (b->d)` to `f a b` to get `f c d`. For example, `(,)` is a `Biapplicative`: there is a way to apply any functions in the pair to translate `(a,b)` into `(c,d)`

```
biap (f,g) (x,y) = (f x, g y)
```

`Data.Biapplicative` defines `biliftA2` to "lift" a pair of functions `a->c->e` and `b->d->f` - constructs a function of two arguments of type `(a,b)` and `(c,d)`

```
biliftA2 f g = \(x,y) (z,t) -> (f x z, g y t)
```

So `biliftA2` constructs a function that can be used in `scanl1` to do the necessary folding. `flip const` will ignore the first projection of the previous pair, and `(+)` will add up the second projection of the previous and next pair.

Comment: Can you explain this one a bit more? I know I've accepted an answer, but I'm still learning from the other answers here, and I'm not sure how to read yours.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist I added more, let me know if you need more detail.

Comment: Wow, that was like math class! :) Are functor, bifunctor, and biapplicative typeclasses? Or are they just useful distinctions? Also, I'm still not sure I know what `flip const` does. Thanks again for all the extra detail. Glad I finally got a chance to read it through and soak it all in!

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist yes, they are typeclasses. `flip` flips over the arguments of the given function. `const` ignores the second argument. `flip const` flips the arguments of `const`, so now the first argument gets ignored, and the second is returned as-is. `flip const` is the same as `const id`.